# How to create autocomplete with more than one value in Drupal 8

Tags: hooks

Im building a form with some autocomplete fields.

I need to get the values from the previous field so i can do a condition to filter values, for example

I have vehicle brand and model,  i need to show models based on brand, without using parent child just because is coming from external api, so i think it would be possible to pass the vehicule model to the brand

I have this already:

```
$form['cbrand'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Select Brand'),
      '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'vehicles.brand',
      '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => array('field_name' => 'brand'),
      '#required' => true,
    );

    $form['cmodel'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Select Model'),
      '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'vehicles.model',
      '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => array('field_name' => 'mode'),
      '#required' => true,
    );
```

Then i have created the controllers

example:

```
public function cmodel(request $request) {
    $string = $request->query->get('q');
    $matches = array();
      $query = db_select('brand', 'm')
          ->fields('m', array('cmodel'))
          ->condition('cmodel', $string . '%', 'LIKE')
          ->groupBy('cmodel')
          ->execute()
          ->fetchAll();
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $matches[] = array('value' => $row->cmodel);
    }

    return new JsonResponse($matches);
  }
```

On this controller i would like to add a new condition based on first textfield.